# 'App_LocalResources/ is not allowed because the application is precompiled in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am seeing the following error from my application:

> The directory '/Form/Task/App_LocalResources/' is not allowed because
>   the application is precompiled.

After publishing some of the form of my application give that problem. I tried by deleting `PrecompiledApp.config` but it does not work.

[image: The directory '/Form/Task/App_LocalResources/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled.]

Comment: if you have an `App_LocalResources` folder in the published site/app, try deleting it; i think it should have been compiled into the app_code folder so it should not be there.

Comment: ***Web Site project or  Web Application*** ?

Comment: Does your `Whatever.resx` files have a build action of "Embedded Resource"? I ran into the same issue of it working on my machine, but breaking in a deployment. Changing the build action from "Content" to "Embedded Resource" was the fix for my case.